# Is there a way to activate RDP from command line

Tags: windows

Is there a way to activate RDP from command line

Hi i just have a question with only command line is possibly there is a way to active RDP ?

Comment: by dos - do you mean command prompt?

Comment: `mstsc /?` [The Windows command prompt is NOT a DOS prompt!](https://scalibq.wordpress.com/2012/05/23/the-windows-command-prompt-is-not-a-dos-prompt/)

Comment: What do you mean by "activate RDP" ? Start the client from the command-line or configure the system to be a RDP server and allow incoming RDP ?

Comment: Hello dos meaning command promt i want to allow machine to available for RDP connection

Comment: @AlaraDickson - Edit your question in order to clarify it

Answer (score -2):

To enable incoming RDP sessions, run these two commands in an elevated command prompt:

> netsh firewall set service remoteadmin enable
>
> netsh firewall set service remotedesktop enable

You'll get a warning that "netsh firewall" is deprecated, but it works anyway.

Comment: The question doesn't say anything about the *firewall*

Comment: The question is unclear, but assuming the aim is to enable RDP *service* - that's one way to accomplish it via CLI.

Comment: I mean what i just want to do using the only command to achieve it.. I will try thoese 2 commands and let you know if works out

Comment: This doesn't enable the Remote Desktop services, either. It simply enables inbound RDP traffic. As for unclear questions it's best to get the OP to clarify before answering.